# How do I add a click event on OpenLayers 4?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I need to attach an event listener to a feature in OpenLayers 4.
I've tried the *feature.on('click',function(){...})* but it is not working.
How can i add tan event to a feature?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `click` event registered for a feature `ol.Feature` object. But `click` event is present for `ol.Map`. Use `forEachFeatureAtPixel` method to get all the features at a pixel and compare it with the feature for which you want to add a listener.

**Relevant Code :**

```
var featureListener = function ( event ) {
    console.log("featureListenerCalled");
    alert("Feature Listener Called");
};

map.on('click', function(event) {

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature,layer) {
        if ( feature.getId() == "IND" ) {
                feature.setStyle(listenerStyle);
                featureListener(event);
        }
    });
});
```

I have created this pluckr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/t6OLmhDTbWt3szpsJxP8?p=preview) which demonstrates this. Click on India map.

Answer (score 2):

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat])),
  adres: adres
  //population: 4000,
  //rainfall: 500
});

// iconFeatureA is an array that gets all features on mouse click pixel location

map.on('click', function(e) {
  var iconFeatureA = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel);
  if (iconFeatureA !== null) {
    var adres = iconFeatureA[0].get("adres");
    alert(adres);
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid bubbling 
  }
});
```