# Openlayers 4 Marker Events (8302859777)

Tags: dom-events, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I am working on Openlayer4.
There are no marker events in the official documentation.

So can you please provide me the appropriate link or code to handle the marker events in OpenLayers 4.

Like:

- Marker On Click Event
- Marker Double-Click Event
- Marker Right Click Event
- Marker Mouse Hover Event

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004561/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-on-openlayers-4

Comment: Thank You Christophe Roussy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a click event on OpenLayers 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004561/how-do-i-add-a-click-event-on-openlayers-4)